# How to decode pcapy output into readable format?

Tags: python, byte, libpcap

I am using Python 3 to retrieve HTTP headers from pcapy output. This shouldn't be that difficult, but I am having a lot of difficulty getting the packets into something readable which is preventing me from continuing any further. I am only allowed to use pcapy and other Python standard library tools for this.

```
import pcapy
devs = pcapy.findalldevs()
(head, payload) = pcapy.open_live(devs[0],65536,0,0).next()
print(payload)
```

returns a byte string of a packet (any packet):

```
b'\xe8*\xea1\xd82d\xe5\x99\xcf`\x90\x08\x00E\x00\x01\xe1\xab(@\x005\x06\xbfA\x97e\x81E\xc0\xa8\x00Z\x00P\x93.\xad\xc8%\xe7\xe0\x95"\x9e\x80\x18\x00N=\\\x00\x00\x01\x01\x08\n\x17\x00\x07&\ty\xc8\xa0HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nCache-Control: private\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nX-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\nX-Request-Guid: 037ce974-4c4a-4044-8721-590f1544a8b6\r\nContent-Length: 42\r\nAccept-Ranges: bytes\r\nDate: Sun, 02 Oct 2016 04:44:36 GMT\r\nVia: 1.1 varnish\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nX-Served-By: cache-nrt6123-NRT\r\nX-Cache: MISS\r\nX-Cache-Hits: 0\r\nX-Timer: S1475383476.794922,VS0,VE165\r\nX-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off\r\n\r\n'
```

Some parts of the returned payload are human readable, others are not and I assume are encoded in ASCII.

At this point I got lost, as we were just told we could "write our own struct" to parse this data with zero prior knowledge of how it works.

How would I be able to decode the rest of the byte string while preserving what is already human-readable? The HTTP headers are already displayed, however I am interesting in retrieving the source and destination IP addresses associated with the headers.

Comment: What code have you tried to solve this?